# How to determine an ODE based on a general solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the general solution $y(x) = Ee^x + De^{-x} + Fxe^x$, $E,D,F$ are reals arbitary constants.  I need to find a 3rd order, linear, homogeneous ODE by this.

I know there are a few things I can do, for example, finding the first, second and third derivatives.

$ y'(x) = Ee^x-De^{-x}+F\left(e^x+e^xx\right)$

$ y''(x) = e^xE+e^{-x}D+F\left(2e^x+e^xx\right)$

$ y'''(x) = e^{x}E-De^{-x}+F\left(3e^x+e^xx\right)$

Writing the general  form of the ODE, I get:

$ay'''(x) + by''(x) + cy'(x) + dy(x)=0$

So I can substitute y(x) and the rest of the derivatives into the ODE. But not sure how to proceed after that? I can group the coefficients of $Ee^x, De^{-x}$ and so on, but then how can I find the constants $a,b,c,d$?

Can I set the coefficient = 0 for all of them?

Comment: If one were to continue your method, then you would want to group coefficients of $e^x$, $e^{-x}$, and $xe^x$ and use the fact that the set $\{e^x, e^{-x}, xe^x\}$ is linearly independent to solve for $a, b, c, d$. Note that the solutions will not be unique because $\lambda a, \lambda b, \lambda c, \lambda d$ are also solutions, which means you may set $a = 1$ without loss of generality.

Comment: Yep, that should work. It might simplify things though if you first let $x=0$. Then  plug in the derivatives into the general expression. You'll get sums of multiples of $a,b,c,d$ with $E,D,F$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\hat{D}=d/dx$. Suppose you have $\hat{D}^2(\hat{D}-2)y=y'''-2y''=0$. Then as a trial we let $y=e^{kx}$. Swap it in to get $(k^3-2k^2)e^{kx}=0\implies k^2(k-2)=0$. $k=0$ is a double root, i.e. has multiplicity 2.  $y=c_1+c_2x+c_3e^{2x}$. You translate the differential equation into an auxiliary equation, then use those roots to find your solutions. If you have any repeated roots, supposing your root is $k$,  then your solutions are  $e^{kx}$ times a polynomial in $x$ with degree one less than the multiplicity of $k$.  Use the same reasoning backwards.

$y=Ee^x+De^{-x}+Fxe^x=e^x(E+Fx) +De^{-x}$

This tells us that the roots of the auxiliary equation are  $1$ and $-1$ with
1 having multiplicity 2. This says the auxiliary equation is $(x-1)^2(x+1)$. Now we essentially swap $\hat{D}$ for $x$ to get $(\hat{D}-1)^2(\hat{D}+1)y=0$.

Now you can check.

$(\hat{D}-1)^2(\hat{D}+1)y=(\hat{D}-1)(\hat{D}^2-1)y=(\hat{D}^3-\hat{D}^2-\hat{D}+1)y=0.$

$y=Ee^x+De^{-x}+Fxe^x$

$y'=(E+F+Fx)e^x-De^{-x}$

$y''=(E+2F+Fx)e^x+De^{-x}$

$y'''= (E+3F+Fx)e^x-De^{-x}$

$y'''-y''-y'+y= -(E+Fx)e^x-De^{-x}+(Ee^x+De^{-x}+Fxe^x)=0$

So it is indeed a solution to the equation.

Comment: Sign error in the last line, the last ODE doesn't match the earlier $D$-operator form

Comment: I think I skipped a step by combining some terms, but the arithmetic checks out.

Comment: I'm referring to the leftmost equation in the last line; $-y$ should be $+y$. Everything else indeed checks out

Comment: I see. Fixed. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I just cannot understand how you know how to approach this. for example letting $D = d/dx$. Can you comment on what I did as well? If I were to continue with my answer, what would be the next steps? Or am I just completely wrong? I think I need to use the homogenous part of the information. 

I could never see the problem the way you did.

Comment: Look up Linear Differential Operators, eigen values and eigen functions. I used some techniques from linear algebra. Actually your solution uses linear algebra too. Since differentiation is a linear operator, it opens the door for breaking up solutions into eigen functions which helps simplify problems.

Comment: I wonder if using $D$ as both the operator and constant is a source of OP's confusion? Maybe swapping out one of the $D$s with a different notation (e.g. $\delta,\Delta,\mathcal{D}$ etc) would help.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiate the solution twice:

$$y = D e^{-x} + E e^x + Fxe^x \\
\implies y'' = D e^{-x} + E e^x + F (x+2)e^x = y + 2Fe^x$$

Let $z=y''-y$, then differentiate again to recover the third-order ODE:

$$z = 2 F e^x \implies z' = 2 F e^x = z \\
\implies z'-z = y'''-y''-y'+y=0$$

Comment: @Gonçalo Thanks, there should have been only one instance of differentiating "again"

Comment: Thanks for the help. The thing is I dont know how you know to make $z = y'' - y$ and why differentiating it again can recover the 3rd order ODE. I havent studied 3rd order ODE only 2nd.

Comment: @CountDOOKU We don't need to introduce $z$ at all, it's just a means of keeping the workspace neater. All we've done here is to differentiate both sides of$$y''-y=2Fe^x$$to get$$y'''-y'=2Fe^x$$and since both RHSs are the same, we get the third-order equation we wanted. We are reverse-engineering an ODE from the solution, not the other way around. We don't need to be experts on $3^{\rm rd}$ order ODES to come to this conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed substitute $y(x)$, $y'(x)$, $y''(x)$, and $y'''(x)$ in your general form of $ay'''(x) + by''(x) + cy'(x) + dy(x) = 0$ of the ODE.

You will then get
$$E f(a,b,c,d) e^x + Dg(a,b,c,d) e^{-x} + Fh(a,b,c,d) e^x + Fj(a,b,c,d) x e^x = 0,$$ where $f$, $g$, $h$, and $j$ are linear combinations of $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$.

As the above equation has to be $0$ for all combinations of $E$, $D$, and $F$ and all $x$, you have to find $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ such that $f(a,b,c,d)$, $g(a,b,c,d)$, $h(a,b,c,d)$, and $j(a,b,c,d)$ are all zero.